# Android: How can I overlay an ImageView with graphics?

Tags: android

Apologies for the total beginner's question but I'm tearing my hair out here ... 
I have a simple view with a couple of widgets on an ImageView background. Overlaying everything is a transparent ImageView on which I would like to draw various text and graphics. The intention was to draw the graphics on the transparent ImageView2.

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
        android:src="@drawable/transparent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.overlay;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    DrawView drawView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            drawView = new DrawView(this);
//              setContentView(drawView);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

DrawView.java:

```
package com.example.overlay;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int w = getWidth(), h=getHeight();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setTextSize(20);
        canvas.drawText("Android", w/3, h/2, paint);
    }

}
```

It's obvious to even me that this won't work because I haven't associated the onDraw() method with the transparent overlay imageView2.
If I use the 'setContentView(drawView);'then I loose the background, etc., under a white background ... if I use the 'setContentView(R.layout.main);'then I don't get the text.
  So the question is, how can I associatiate the transparent ImageView with the onDraw() method?
  Is this even the best approach?
I've been googling for days; perhaps I just don't understand what questions to ask :)

Comment: You need to add DrawView to the layout.xml. Then call setContentView(R.layout.main); Instead of putting a built in view like ImageView, replace ImageView with your class name (You may have to give the full class path com.your.app.DrawView).

Comment: Thanks for the response but, like I said, I'm a total (nearly bald) beginner! Any chance of a bit of code? I tried '     <com.example.overlay.DrawView 
         android:id="@+id/overlay"
         android:src="@drawable/transparent"
            android:clickable="true"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 but Eclipse is twittering on about 'Custom view DrawView is not using the 2- or 3-argument View constructors; XML attributes will not work' and I've absolutely no idea what that means. In any event, the app crashes in the emulator.

Comment: Now here's a thing ... Having changed the main.xml to include '     <com.example.overlay.DrawView 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>' the 'Android' now text appears in Eclipse's Graphical Layout view of the xml! It still crashes in the emulator though with 'Error inflating class com.example.overlay.DrawView' on line #34. Is it really this difficult to use graphics in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Nathan touches upon this in his comment...

You need to add your custom `DrawView` to your xml layout, so you will have:

```
<com.example.overlay.DrawView
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

In your `DrawView` class you then need a constructor that takes these attributes you've added in the xml layout. The standard constructor you will require will take the `Context` and an `AttributeSet` as below:

```
public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

You can then override the `onDraw` method as you already do, and you can then manipulate the `Canvas`.

Ensure when your `Canvas` is passed in to the `onDraw` method it is the width and height of the screen with the `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods. If it isn't then you can set the canvas from a new `Bitmap` and then draw on the canvas as you are doing.

There is a helpful article on creating a custom `View` over at the Android Developer website which is a good read. You can find it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html).

Comment: Nathan and biddulph.r: Thanks so much for that - it now works a treat.